# Will new APNS certificate invalidate previous auth key - iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using APNS auth key for push notification in my iOS app which directs notification via Firebase cloud messaging. App is live on appstore and notifications are working fine. However, I have to integrate a chat SDK which requires APNS certificate for push notification for that app. I haven't created any APNS cert yet. My doubt is if I create a new APNS certificate, will it invalidate my previous APNS auth key? I dont want live users to stop receiving notifications.

Comment: don't delete that cert from apple dev account than it will work or why you need to create new cert for chat sdk. mean can't u use the previous one.

Comment: download previous cert from apple dev account and use it for chat sdk.

Comment: @MRizwan33 there is no previous certificate. I have not created any APNS certificate. Push notifications are working using APNS auth key. Auth keys are modern methods for push notifications in ios. They never gets expired.